# oracle weblogic OAM servlet proxy - how to propagate OAMAuthnCookie

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, single-sign-on, oam

I am trying to wrestle with SSO in weblogic version is 12.2.1.3. We have integrated it with OAM/OID, within a larger application comprising of Oracle Forms & Reports. In addition to Forms, we have various custom servlet-based applications that need to be called from Forms.

This is fine.

Because authentication happens within the Oracle world, through OAM login screen, up to now I didn't have to mess with the Access Management within my Java custom code, apart from getting the username from HTTP headers.

The bad thing is that sometimes we need our servlets to act as middle-man between Forms and Reports. E.g. I need to call various stuff with Reports (on server), transform them and send them back to the client. I know that this doesn't sound right design-wise. But still it's legacy code and we need to make this work - at least need to try..

Previously we used to get away with it passing cookies between requests. But in 11/12g OAM, I am gathering from [here](http://fusionsecurity.blogspot.com/2011/04/oam-11g-single-sign-on-and-oam-11g.html) that the cookie needed for successful session validation (OAMAuthnCookie) is stripped from the request before reaching my servlet. This seems to happen indeed, basing on the header dumps i am doing, and tracing calls using F12 Developer Tools on the browser.

So.. I have gathered that I need to generate a new OAMAuthnCookie, or something that would create it and attach it to the new http call.. I just would like an expert or somebody who has dealt with this to verify that the following assumption is right - the only way to do this is using OAM SDK (a bit non-intuitive imho).

Another thing - many of the examples that I find about OAM SDK deal with login forms. I don't need to do user authentication, nor do I need to talk with OAM myself to verify if the resource is protected or not. I am dealing with an already authenticated request - need to just somehow get UserSession and user token from HttpServletRequest, in order to generate new OAMAuthnCookie so that my next request (using e.g. apache client) succeeds.. I used to assume that this wouldn't be hard to do, but am a bit stumped now.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with OAM SDK, as far as I cursively saw (at the time of writing this, we were using Weblogic 12c with Access Manager that behaves exactly as described in the documents that talk about OAM 11g - therefore I assume that's the version we are using too), involves

- generating ObAccessClient.xml from OAM Console, to establish contact between the code you are working on (which will be called Access Client), and OAM
- including JARs from the downloadable OAM SDK with your application
- writing code in your application (e.g. in authentication filter, or servlet) to establish communication with OAM via its SDK to finally authenticate/authorize etc.

There is a good guide about how to write the code in [Oracle documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/dev.1111/e12491/as_api.htm#CHDBDAGI).

I found also these articles very informative:

- [Oracle Access Management blog](http://oracleaccessmanagement.blogspot.com/2011/03/here-at-oracle-access-management-pm.html)
- [Oracle A-team Best Practices blog](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/oam-11g-single-sign-on-and-oam-11g-cookies)

The code that I had in mind would ultimately generate a new authentication cookie that I would pass to the reports servlet for further authorization (since this cookie is stripped indeed from the request before reaching my application). The only way I found to generate such a cookie would involve changing a setting in OAM console to include another cookie (OAM_IDENTITY_ASSERTION) in the requests, according to [another Oracle A-Team article](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/retrieving-the-oam-sessionid-for-fun-and-profit/).

In the process of the above investigation, I finally stumbled on [this magic reply to a question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3582096) in Oracle forums. According to it, there is a user setting in OAM console, that allows to switch off the default filtering of OAMAuthnCookie.

```
filterOAMAuthnCookie=false
```

In our case, this perfectly suited me. Indeed after the change, the cookie in question was finally reaching my application, with the result of me being able to pass it to subsequent requests to Oracle Reports, without using OAM SDK.